# Extended meaning of Audience

Tags: word-meaning

I wonder if 'audience' has an extended or practical meaning. In the following tech document I see a phrase Developer Audience but I can't understand what it means.

I know what Audience means but presume the meaning as 'notice' in the context. Or is it the formal expression of 'listen!'?

[Developer Audience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-portal#developer-audience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "audience" is the group of people paying attention to or interested in something.

The section heading "developer audience" means that section will describe what types of developers are going to be interested in CryptoAPI. In this case it is C and C++ developers working in windows environments on projects requiring the exchange of documents or data in a secure environment using nonsecure media.